# Assign generic type class implementing interface to generic type being interface

Tags: c#, .net-core, object-oriented-analysis

I'm not sure if my question is clear so I will make it clear by the code:

Basically I have a loader interface, with a generic type being an interface.
Here, both Cat and Dog implements IAnimal.

```
private readonly IAnimalLoader<Cat> _catLoader;
private readonly IAnimalLoader<Dog> _dogLoader;

private IAnimalLoader<IAnimal> animalLoader;

public AnimalService(IAnimalLoader<Cat> catLoader,
                     IAnimalLoader<Dog> dogLoader)
{
    _catLoader = catLoader;
    _dogLoader = dogLoader;
}
```

Problem is when trying to assign either of the loader to animalLoader:

```
if (animal == AnimalType.Cat)
{
    animalLoader = _catLoader;
}
else
{
    animalLoader = _dogLoader;
}
```

C# complains about **no implicit conversion from `Cat` to `IAnimal`**, even though it implements it. No cast seems to fix the issue.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is IAnimalLoader for clarification

```
public interface IAnimalLoader<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAllQueryable();
    Task<T> GetAsync(string id);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at covariance: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/

Comment: Also, can you show us the code for `IAnimalLoader`

Comment: @Sean question updated with details

Comment: Why do you need to assign `_catLoader` to `animalLoader`? As you're storing both why not just call them?

Comment: @Sean has it - basically, the issue is that you can't go back and forth between `IAnimalLoader<IAnimal>` and `IAnimalLoader<Cat>` without marking up the interface a little more with the keywords `in` or `out` so that it knows what to expect as the types are different. If the types are different and there are no such markings, the only thing C# can do is check for an implicit conversion from one type to the other, which explains the error you see. Check Sean's link for more info on what to do instead.

Comment: @ArthClement As an option, you can introduce a non-generic version of `IAnimalLoader` interface and create a variable of this type to assign an instance

Comment: Difficult to explain in fact.
I need to be able to assign ``_catLoader`` to ``animalLoader`` because later I need to retrieve data from database, so calling service again but don't have the infomation on whether I'm dealing with a cat or a dog. So I need loader to be already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Cat` implements `IAnimal`, `IAnimalLoader<Cat>` has no such relationship with `IAnimalLoader<IAnimal>`, which is what the error message is about.

Generally, one needs to mark the generic parameter as covariant for the conversion to succeed, the syntax is `out T` IIRC, otherwise, check the C# language reference on generics' variance.

Updated (Thanks to the comment below): In your case, even that is not possible since one of the types, `Task<T>`, is invariant. Only interfaces can be marked as variant, classes cannot be.

Comment: You can't declare `T` as covariant here, because `Task<T>` is invariant

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I have to get rid of my Task?

Comment: No one except you can answer that. If that Task must be there, you may be able to hide it behind some interface and make that variant. May or may not work though.